# Binary search is not able to search for data with spaces in it, how can this be resolved?

Tags: c#

This binary search works for all strings, except for those with spaces. The NameBox.Text is where the input for the search is given. The point is to search a title in the Namebox and have it read in the "Game" which is a listbox of strings, then if the game is found, to populate the NameBox, PlatformBox and CostBox fields with the games data.

```
private void BinarySearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(NameBox.Text))
    {
        log.Items.Clear();
        log.Items.Add("Please enter a string");
        return;
    }
    int min = 0;
    int max = Game.Length - 1;
    string search = NameBox.Text;
    while (min <= max)
    {
        int mid = (min + max) / 2;
        if (Game[mid] == search)
        {
            log.Items.Clear();
            log.Items.Add("Game " + Game[mid] + " found!");
            NameBox.Text = Game[mid];
            PlatformBox.Text = Platform[mid];
            String cost1 = Cost[mid].ToString("$0.00");
            CostBox.Text = cost1;
            NameBox.Focus();
            return;
        }
        else if (Game[mid] != search)
        {
            max = mid - 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            min = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    log.Items.Clear();
    log.Items.Add("Game not found");
    NameBox.Focus();
}
```

Comment: "is not working" is not very specific. Can you please [edit] your question to let us know what the expected result is and how your code fails to achieve it? [Reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may be useful

Comment: Did you confirm that `search` has what is expected?

Comment: @tymtam Yes, it always does. I tested it by displaying the values[0 to 2] in a status strip and they are all correct.

Comment: Note that the else branch will never be entered. Probaby your second if condition is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `else if` to read as

```
else if (Game[mid].CompareTo(search)>0)
```

Your `else if` and your `else` effectively are the same thing at the moment. **A binary search needs to operate on sorted data**, it needs to examine the mid value and decide "is this less than, or same as, or greater than what I'm looking for" - that's three questions

Right now your code only asks two questions: "is it same as, else is is not same as, else [it is not same as]"

CompareTo will determine "if the value at the mid point is alphabetically greater than the search" which means you can then know the value you seek is in the lower half of the array and you can reduce the maximum

This makes the logic three state (if found, else if term being sought is in the lower part of the array reduce max, else term must be in upper part so raise minimum)

Here it is working, finding data with spaces in: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dE5wdw

Comment: This causes searching to break for any non default listbox items. and they do not do the same thing.

Comment: What is a not default list item?

Comment: Information loaded into the list, its received fine which I have tested. It does cause another problem somewhere else that is not related to my post here. It does not introduce any new characters other than spaces.

Comment: You aren't making much sense. Please see this demonstration of your algorithm, plus my fix, correctly finding a game with spaces in the name https://dotnetfiddle.net/dE5wdw

Comment: Like I said, your solution DOES work, just not for default listbox items, upon startup it is populated with "~empty - $0", with my code, I am able to search games that are added such as "Minecraft" or words without spaces, however with my code, when searching for a game like "God of War" with spaces, it cannot find it. With your code, it cannot find either.

Comment: I'm not saying your code is poorly written or bad or whatever, it just simply does not work for this circumstance.

Comment: Make sure your data is sorted. Binary search only works on sorted data. You cannot search on `new[]{"Minecraft","God of War","Final Fantasy 78"}` because this data is exactly the wrong order. If you search "final fantasy" it'll hit the mid "God of war", decide that F is less than G and try looking in the first half of the array but the game is in the second half. C# doesn't care whether the data in a string is a space or not (it never even gets to the part of the string where the space is). Give me the exact data you're failing with and I'll adjust my C# fiddle to contain it and prove it works

Comment: Specify sorted data, I have a method to sort it alphabetically, which is not done in binary search but in I have tried, with your solution, to the same result. Its a little bit more complicated than just giving you the data, I would have to send your the whole program.

Comment: My comment above has been edited since you wrote your comment. I don't really know what else to tell you; take my fiddle, change the order so the games are in reverse, and watch the search fail. Tell me exactly what data, in what order, you're applying this algoeithm to and I'll tell you whether it works or why it fails. Data has to be sorted, and it doesn't matter how it is sorted, so long as the sort algorithm and the search algorithm use the same decision engine when asking "is x less than or greater than y". - a reverse alphabetical sorter will say "yes, A is greater than B"

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/zoyGqkd.png keep in mind the $ is not actually stored, its just displayed like that in the listbox, costbox and total box.

Comment: And it doesn't matter that is does that, so long as when your binary searcher is searching it also makes the same decision when it encounters a B and is looking for an A, and correctly discards half the array

Comment: That data is not sorted. In C# `~` is less than `A` so all those `~empty` should be at the start of the list. Right now if you seek `God of..` it will hit a midpoint that contains `~empty` and because G is greater than tilde assume that God of war is after the midpoint, when it is actually before (your sort algo and your search algo do not agree)

Comment: Depending on your culture, "~empty" might in fact sort before "God of War"

Comment: Doesn't work (data not properly sorted-how you have it): https://dotnetfiddle.net/jUi5u2

Comment: Does work(data properly sorted): https://dotnetfiddle.net/1pCV1f

Comment: Does work(~empty removed): https://dotnetfiddle.net/rw6O92

Comment: whether the data contains spaces or not is mostly moot, by the way; C# string comparer will (mostly) never hit any data with a space because none of your strings are identical up to a first space. C# only needs to check 1 character to know that Minecraft != God of War, for example. The only time spaces ever even factor is if comparing "God of War" to "God of War" and for that, the binary search algo needs to work correctly :)

Comment: @Klaus good point. I should have said "in this culture [you and I both seem to share]" rather than "in C#"

Comment: How do you guys propose I implement this? I cant simply remove the "~empty", I want to show the user how many spaces they have available.  Using - instead of "~empty" sorts the games at the bottom and search doesnt work because of the empty or -. Any ideas?

Comment: As @CaiusJard wrote several times: you absolutely have to make sure that `Games` is sorted in a way compatible with the comparison function used in the `else if` - otherwise you cannot use binary search. So your options are: 1. use another seach algorithm, 2. put the "~empty" entries at the top, 3. use another character instead of "~" which sorts after all your game names.

Comment: I'd remove the empty entries from the listbox. They don't do anything to make the UI clearer or easier to use, they're just visual clutter. If you want to have a max number of games you will search, do it as a counter and have a label like `inventoryCountLabel.Text = $"Empty slots still available: {10 - listbox.Items.Count}";`